# How to stop the movement of seekBar past a dynamic point

Tags: android, seekbar

I am trying to stop the movement of a certain seekBar after it reaches a dynamic point (calculated from subtraction the setMax() value and other seekBar.getProgress()). 
I tried using the onTouchEvent() but couldn't stop the movement of the bar and setting manually the seekBar.setProgress() but it only jumps to that point and continue moving with the finger.

```
  sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            sb1.setMax(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));
            if (progress >= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()) - sb2.getProgress() - sb3.getProgress())
                sb1.setProgress(progress);
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }


    });

    sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            sb2.setMax(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()));

            if (progress >= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()) - sb1.getProgress() - sb3.getProgress())
                sb2.setProgress(progress);
            tv2.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
        }

    });
```

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
if (progress >= Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()) - sb2.getProgress() - sb3.getProgress())
    sb1.setProgress(progress);
```

Inside your `sb1` change listener. But that doesn't really make sense, because `progress` is already the progress of `sb1`. I think you should change this:

```
sb1.setProgress(progress);
```

To:

```
sb1.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString()) - sb2.getProgress() - sb3.getProgress());
```

The value I got for that progress was from your `if` condition. Basically when the progress is greater than that value, you just set it to the value. So this way, it cannot be dragged past that point.

Do the same thing for your other listeners as well.

Comment: Thank you! With this answer I have managed to stop the movement of the Thumb-bar (although the progress is still moving but I can find a way to work around it).

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the seekbar object after you have reached the desired progress:

```
sb1.setEnable (false)
```

Comment: This method freezes the SeekBar without the option to keep using it afterwards.